# How to use list comprehension for excluding maximum value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input list and I want to make another list that excludes the maximum value and gets the sum of the new list

here is my code so far:

```
arr= list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))[:5]
print(arr)
x=list(sum(arr[x] if x!= max(arr)))
print(x)
```

However, there is a syntax error when I output it and I'm not sure where the problem is in the code. It would be helpful if someone could explain how to use list comprehensions as well.

Comment: `sum(arr[x] if x!= max(arr)` is bad. Move `m = max(arr)` out of the loop, or else it gets re-calcualted, making the overall algorithm quadratic time instead of linear time

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the maximum value appears multiple times in the list?

Comment: What you probably meant to write was `x = sum([n for n in arr if n != max(arr)])`. Note that in your code, you don't initialize `x` anywhere. The structure of the loop which is supposed to filter the max value is not present in your code.

Comment: @paul -Thank you so much, that was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try:

```
l = [1,3,5,8,9]
l_copy = l.copy() # just not to mutate the original list
l_copy = l_copy.remove(max(l_copy))
res = sum(l_copy)
```

Explain:

```
max(l_copy) # return the max value in l
l_copy = l_copy.remove(max(l_copy)) # remove the max value of the list

sum(l) # sum all list except the max value
```

Pay attention to an input of empty list..